# Drag Drop between GridViews

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have two `GridView`s in my Page which contains multiple items. One is for **Existing Items** and one for **User Cart**. The user should drag and drop an item in order to add it to his buying list.

How can I enable drag drop between two or more `GridView`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/going_metro/archive/2012/07/16/drag-and-drop-within-a-grouped-grid-view.aspx) is an example of how to drag and drop between different groups within one grouped grid.